# Problema en un programa muy simple de C++

Tags: c++, clase

Hoy escribí esto que es muy sencillo para practicar pero no obtuve el resultado esperado, ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

La idea es aprender a usar clases y para ello utilizo un constructor para crear 4 Alumnos, luego hacerlos rendir un examen en el cual obtienen una nota aleatoria. Finalmente hay una tercera función para hacerlos decir qué nota obtuvieron.

Esto lo que se obtiene al ejecutarlo:

[image: Resultado de ejecucion]

El código es:

```
#include <iostream>

class Alumno {
private:

    enum Materias : int { Matematica, Historia, Biologia };
    int m_nota[3];
    std::string m_nombre;
public:
    Alumno(std::string nombre) {
        m_nombre = nombre;
    }

    void rendirExamen() {
        m_nota[0] = rand() % 11;
        m_nota[1] = rand() % 11;
        m_nota[2] = rand() % 11;
    }

    void decirNota() {

        std::cout << m_nombre << ": " << m_nota[Matematica] << " en Matematica." << std::endl;
        std::cout << m_nombre << ": " << m_nota[Historia] << " en Historia." << std::endl;
        std::cout << m_nombre << ": " << m_nota[Biologia] << " en Biologia." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Alumno Juan("Juan"), Marcos("Marcos"), Pedro("Pedro"), Martin("Martin");

    Juan.rendirExamen();
    Juan.decirNota();

    Marcos.rendirExamen();
    Marcos.decirNota();

    Pedro.rendirExamen();
    Pedro.decirNota();

    Martin.rendirExamen();
    Martin.decirNota();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código en [este fiddle](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php) y funciona correctamente, muestra la info para todos los alumnos que instancias.

Comment: Entonces es un problema de Visual Studio, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Parecía ser un bug, cuando ejecuté el programa con la consola maximizada funcionó correctamente